# Private Custom Angular2 Module npm package not showing for import

Tags: angular, npm

I am attempting to make a private npm package with a angular module in it for consumption among other apps of mine. I have followed https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435 everything is building on the package side, and publishing but when i try and import into my core module in my main app it cant find the package. I see the package in the node packages but im not sure i am missing my typings or what is going on. I honestly am not sure which side to start with either.

TLDR What makes my import {} from 'package' find the 'package' portion because i seem to be lacking that functionality on my custom package.

Comment: Did you specify the correct `main` property in your package.json? See https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

Comment: I have not, should that be my module?

Comment: The should be the public api of your npm package. In your case this might be only the Angular module. E.g. you can create a `public-api.ts`, which just exports the things, that should be accesable from your package. The `main` entry in your package.json contains the `path/public-api.js`

Comment: Ah ok so i made a portalcore.ts that has the export lines, so that .js needs to be the main?

Comment: Yeah that should work.

Comment: portalcore.ts has export * from './app/core/portalcore.module'; then package has   "main": "portalcore.js",
  "private": false,
  "typings": "./portalcore.d.ts" and it still is not seeing the package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160957/discussion-between-user1552172-and-philipp).